# Wordpress Contact Form Fade In Awkward

Tags: wordpress, fadein, contact-form, contact-form-7

I'm trying to have the contact form on my website to fade in after 4500 milliseconds. As the website loads the contact form stays awkwardly visible until the 4500ms. Then it shows the fade in animation.

How do I get the contact form to stay hidden for the whole 4500ms until the fade in? Example on website: [MvgAvg.com](http://mvgavg.com)

Please and thank you.

Comment: Hide it by default, using `display: none` or any appropriate css class from your stylesheet applying the same style.

Comment: either it's not working, or i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code here on Stackoverflow in this case by [edit]ing your question

Comment: how does one do that please?